# Space between words when writing to csv

Tags: python, csv

when I execute the below lines. I receive a space between each letter and the words do not format properly. any help is appreciated.

```
import csv
with open('u2.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    wf = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter = '\t')
    for key in wordcount.keys():
        wf.writerow("%s %s"  %(key, wordcount[key]))
```

Comment: `wf.writerow` takes a list, not a string. Pass `[key, wordcount[key]]` without any manual formatting.

Comment: Edit the question to include a small example for `wordcount` and also what the output in `u2.csv` should look like. I assume you are using Python 3.x ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Python's CSV library, the `writerow()` function takes a list and writes each element into the file with your chosen delimiter between each element. So you need to pass it a list. In your case, you need to create a list of two elements by enclosing the values in `[ ]` as follows:

```
import csv

wordcount = {'hello' : 2, 'world' : 5}

with open('u2.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter='\t')

    for word, count in wordcount.items():
        csv_output.writerow([word, count])
```

This approach also avoids you having to lookup the count for each key.

You would get an output `u2.csv` looking like:

```
world   5
hello   2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you:

```py
import csv

Lists = [jassim, Greeshma, Abhirami, sourav]

with open ("name_list", "w", newline = ' ') as list:
    for names in Lists:
        Writer = CSV.writer(list , delimiter='\t')
        Writer.write(names)
```